# Event listener for when child of parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-listener

I currently have an issue where I want to be able to check when a event is click. I want to use event delegation for this and so I have setup an event listener on a parent div, which listens for clicks:

```
document.querySelector('.side-nav').addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.target.data.set.param);
});
```

This is my DOM:

```html
<div class="side-nav">
    <div class="side-nav-button side-nav-active pointer" id="dashboard-shortcut" title="Home" data-page="dashboard">
        <p class="side-nav-button-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="side-nav-button side-nav-active pointer" id="another-div-shortcut" title="page2" data-page="page2">
        <p class="side-nav-button-icon"><i class="fas fa-cross"></i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to get the `data-page` attribute when the right div is clicked, ie when the div `dashboard-shortcut` is clicked. Is there any way that I can do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you expect to have elements added dynamically, don't use event delegation, simply attach a listener on each target, in this case the `.side-nav > [data-page]` elements.

With that you avoid all detection issues, like which actual `div` where clicked etc., where `this` will be the targeted element, e.g. `this.dataset.page`.

*...and a bonus; less code, less error prone, easier maintenance.*

*Note, you used `data.set.param`, should be `dataset.param`, where `param` here is `page` (`data-page`)*

Stack snippet

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.side-nav > [data-page]').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.dataset.page);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="side-nav">
    <div class="side-nav-button side-nav-active pointer" id="dashboard-shortcut" title="Home" data-page="dashboard">
        <p class="side-nav-button-icon"><i class="fas fa-home">Home</i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="side-nav-button side-nav-active pointer" id="another-div-shortcut" title="page2" data-page="page2">
        <p class="side-nav-button-icon"><i class="fas fa-cross">Page2</i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Based on a comment, where OP said they do load elements dynamically, added a 2nd sample.

Using `if (e.target !== this && this.contains(e.target))` we can check so it is not the `.side.nav` itself (`e.target !== this`) someone clicked on, but one of its children (`this.contains(e.target)`), before continue.

And if, with `e.target.closest('[data-page]').dataset.page` we get the targeted element.

*Note, as mentioned in another comment, if you have nested `.side-nav` with children having the same classes/attribute, you might need to adjust, where e.g. extending the selector for `closest()`, to `closest('.side-nav > [data-page]')`, should be enough, still, difficult to say with certainty.*

Stack snippet

```js
document.querySelector('.side-nav').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this && this.contains(e.target)) {    
    console.log(e.target.closest('[data-page]').dataset.page);  
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="side-nav">
    <div class="side-nav-button side-nav-active pointer" id="dashboard-shortcut" title="Home" data-page="dashboard">
        <p class="side-nav-button-icon"><i class="fas fa-home">Home</i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="side-nav-button side-nav-active pointer" id="another-div-shortcut" title="page2" data-page="page2">
        <p class="side-nav-button-icon"><i class="fas fa-cross">Page2</i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, I expect the elements to be added dynamically.

Comment: @dan123123 Updated and added a 2nd sample, which work with dynamically added children of `.side-nav`.

Comment: Why not use `[...this.children].includes(e.target)` instead of  `e.target !== this && this.contains(e.target)`? Shorter and more readable imo.

Comment: @connexo Thanks, shorter, yes, more readable,...depends on who you ask :)

Comment: @LGSon sorry for not getting back sooner - Works perfectly, thank you! I added it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: @dan123123 Thanks...and don't worry about how fast you reply/get back. Always take the time you need, to test and consider which answer works best, and when you are done, you accept and/or upvote the answers.

Comment: @LGSon thats very kind, thank you :). Again, thank you so much for your time and effort for this post, it really helped me. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

// use **closest** method for finding actual element

```
document.querySelector('.side-nav').addEventListener('click', e => {
    var elem = e.target.closest("[data-page]");
    if (elem && elem.getAttribute('data-page') !== 'root') {
        console.log(elem.getAttribute("data-page"));
    }
});
```

**Note: prevent stop finding element till root**

```
<div class="side-nav" data-page='root'>
    <div class="side-nav-button side-nav-active pointer" id="dashboard-shortcut" title="Home" data-page="dashboard">
        <p class="side-nav-button-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></p>
    </div>
   <div class="side-nav-button side-nav-active pointer" id="another-div-shortcut" title="page2" data-page="page2">
        <p class="side-nav-button-icon"><i class="fas fa-cross"></i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If there's an element beyond `.side-nav` with that attribute and only `.side-nav` is clicked (which can happen if you have paddings and such), will get the wrong `data-page`. EDIT: Didn't noticed the `root` thingy. Pretty clever.

Comment: That's easily solved with `e.target.closest(".side-nav > [data-page]")`

Comment: And no need to use an extra trick like with `'root'`, simply `e.target !== this` fix that

Comment: @LGSon If there's a nav inside a nav (more usual than you think), then that's also broken (talking about the CSS selector). The `this` thing is better in this case.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález If you look at the selector you'll see I used the child selector `>`, which solves the nested elements case.

Comment: @LGSon Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/omc0ebqr/ it has a nested navigator which it fails. With your `this` or Sandeep `root` thingy, it is solved.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Well, there's always edge cases (if e.g. you use the same name convention in all level, which one shouldn't), and when, they are known and can be dealt with...so because of that I posted one that makes things a lot easier (and IMHO is the most proper way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

The `target` property of an event will be the element clicked. In your scenario the element clicked can be any HTML element you shown in your example: The `p` or the `i` inside the `.side-nav-button`, the `.side-nav-button` itself or even the `.side-nav` where you attach the event.

What I can think of is to get the target element, check if has a `data-page` attribute and if not, go for the parent and repeat the check. This way if, for example, the `i` element is clicked, it will check itself, then will check the `p` and finally its `.side-nav-button`.

Hence:

```
document.querySelector('.side-nav').addEventListener('click', e => {
    let el = e.target;
    // The loop will stop when there's a page dataset
    // Also will stop when the element that is checking is .side-nav (event.currentTarget), as there's no need to check beyond that.
    while(el && el != event.currentTarget && !el.dataset.hasOwnProperty("page")) {
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    let page = el && el.dataset.page;
    if (page) {
        console.log(page);
    }
});
```